# How to get this formatting in python?

Tags: python, fortran

I am trying to translate a fortran code into python, I have this fortran code

```
j=1;
 write(111,11) 'n/a'
11   format('perm   ', a)
do i=1,nnn
  write(111,fmt='(3i10,3e16.8)') i,i,j,perm(i),perm(i),perm(i)
enddo
```

It should write to a file like this

```
perm   n/a
         1         1         1  0.29963005E-11  0.29963005E-11  0.29963005E-11
         2         2         1  0.29963005E-11  0.29963005E-11  0.29963005E-11
         3         3         1  0.29963005E-11  0.29963005E-11  0.29963005E-11
         4         4         1  0.13256129E-10  0.13256129E-10  0.13256129E-10
         5         5         1  0.13256129E-10  0.13256129E-10  0.13256129E-10
         6         6         1  0.13256129E-10  0.13256129E-10  0.13256129E-10
         7         7         1  0.13256129E-10  0.13256129E-10  0.13256129E-10
         8         8         1  0.43202447E-11  0.43202447E-11  0.43202447E-11
         9         9         1  0.43202447E-11  0.43202447E-11  0.43202447E-11
```

What would be the correct way of doing this in python?

Comment: [This project](https://bitbucket.org/brendanarnold/py-fortranformat) may be useful to you if you have a lot of Fortran code

Answer (score 0):

In python you would use string formatting.

Have a look at this:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

EDIT:

Ok, a few things will come in handy for your case. First of all the 'E' presentation type will display a float in exponential notation. For example:

```
print("{:E}".format(0.123456))
output: 1.234560e-01
```

You can change the amount of decimal places shown by adding the 'precision parameter:

```
print("{:.3E}".format(0.123456))
output: 1.235E-01
```

Finally, you will need padding to align the different values in the table:

```
print("{:20.3E}".format(0.123456))
output:            1.235E-01
```

This will ensure that the outputted string has a width of 20 characters. It does this by prepending the number with space characters (' ')

Combining all this knowledge:

```
print("{:10d}{:10d}{:10d}{:16.8E}{:16.8E}{:16.8E}".format(i, i, j, perm(i), perm(i), perm(i))
```

Does this give you enough information?

Comment: I can't figure this out, sorry..I tried it with "{.8f}".format(string) but it's not giving me the desired result

Comment: is it possible to make it print 25.4343 as 0.254343E+02

Comment: As far as I can see, there does not seem to be an option for this. You could probably hack something together that would produce this output, but I'm not sure what the best approach for that would be...

Answer (score 0):

```
f111 = open(...,'w')
...
fmt111 = %10d"*3 + "%16.8E"*3 + "/n"
for i in range(nnn):(3i10,3e16.8)
    f111.write(fmt11%(i,i,j,perm(i),perm(i),perm(i)))
```

I'm not sure if the byte compiler builds the format string each time, but to be on the safe side you can define a constant format outside the loop.

The rationale

1. Open a file for writing (the `,'w'` part)
2. define what in fortran is a format string, it is built using the string    multiplication operator, and the string concatenation operator, `*` and `+`, respectively, and the result is "%10d%10d%10d%16.8E%16.8E%16.8E\n"
3. specify the index and the length of the for loop
4. the `write` method of a `file` object, as returned by the call to `open`, accepts only a string, so a string is built inside the call, using
5. *string interpolation*, that is the values specified in the `tuple` at the right of the interpolation operator, i.e., `%` are transformed to strings according to the rules specified (here the various `%10d` etc) in the string on the left (here `fmt111`) and the resulting strings are "interpolated" in the format string, that is written in the file object (notice the explicit EOL character at the end of the format string)

**BEWARE of the differences in indexing between fortran and python**,

you may want to use

```
    f111.write(fmt11 % (i+1,i+1,j,perm(i),perm(i),perm(i))
```

when you `write` the file, notice that the indices in `perm` go from 0 to `nnn-1`, as it is correct in python, and depending on who's going to consume the file you may prefer one form or the other --- the same reasoning may apply to the number `j` as well.

Comment: I'm a bit curious about  the ratio information/bytes of the tabulation you're going to reply...

Comment: Looking at your comment to other answer by http://stackoverflow.com/users/2009026/gargamel, if you're in this stuff (producing formatted reports, I mean) as a student or as a programmer, DO YOURSELF A FAVOR, go to the link in the answer and get your hand in it, working with the interactive interpreter to  get a feeling of what's going on.  If you feel that presentation is too dry, ask google/etc about 'string interpolation python example tutorial' and choose one that fits your fancy...  To repeat myself, this is important stuff if you're in producing formatted reports using python.

Comment: A good tutorial, that introduces both the `%` and the `.format` sintaxes is to be found at http://www.python-course.eu/python3_formatted_output.php

Comment: Thanks gboffi, i just started learning python and I am shifting from fortran, it was a bit confusing but both answers helped me figure out things, I am reading up on formatting now.

Comment: So you come from fortran... me too.  Welcome!